# HTMLElement.blur method not working in componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It seems as though using the `HTMLElement.blur` does not work as expected when called from `componentWillReceiveProps`, although `HTMLElement.focus` actually *does* work.

Simple repro case (es2015 using babel):

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      index: 0
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", e => this.handleKeyDown(e));
  }

  handleKeyDown(e) {
    let index = this.state.index;
    switch (e.which) {
      case 40: // up arrow
        index = Math.max(0, index - 1);
        break;
      case 38: // down arrow
        index++;
        break;
    }

    this.setState({index});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBox index={this.state.index} />              
        <p>Index: {this.state.index}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class SearchBox extends React.Component {

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.index === 0) {
      console.log('focusing');
      this.textbox.focus(); // this works
    } else {
      console.log('blurring');
      this.textbox.blur(); // this doesn't
    }
  }

  render() {  
    return (
      <input type="text" ref={n => this.textbox = n} />
    );
  }
};
```

I have created a JSBin [here](http://jsbin.com/puceqe/edit?html,js,console,output) that displays the unexpected behavior.

Does anybody have an explanation for this? Is there something about the react lifecycle that I have misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though that was indeed the wrong life-cycle hook to use.

Found this nugget when I re-read the docs:

> **Updating: componentDidUpdate**
>
> `void componentDidUpdate(object prevProps, object prevState)`
>
> Invoked immediately after the component's updates are flushed to the DOM. This method is not called for the initial render.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated.

From [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate)

I moved the relevant code to `componentDidUpdate` and now all works as expected.